# Unable to install pg gem on CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810

Tags: linux, centos, ruby, gem

```
ruby --version ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-linux]

gem --version 3.3.7
```

`PostgreSQL 9.2.24 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44), 64-bit`
When I run

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209797/cant-find-the-postgresql-client-library-libpq), I get

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.3.5/ext
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/ruby -I /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r ./siteconf20220601-102563-hl61l1.rb extconf.rb
Calling libpq with GVL unlocked
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /bin/pg_config
Using libpq from /usr/lib64
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*****************************************************************************

Unable to find PostgreSQL client library.

Please install libpq or postgresql client package like so:
  sudo apt install libpq-dev
  sudo yum install postgresql-devel
  sudo zypper in postgresql-devel
  sudo pacman -S postgresql-libs

or try again with:
  gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config

or set library paths manually with:
  gem install pg -- --with-pg-include=/path/to/libpq-fe.h/ --with-pg-lib=/path/to/libpq.so/

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-pg
        --without-pg
        --enable-gvl-unlock
        --disable-gvl-unlock
        --enable-windows-cross
        --disable-windows-cross
        --with-pg-config
        --without-pg-config
        --with-pg_config
        --without-pg_config
        --with-pg-dir
        --without-pg-dir
        --with-pg-include
        --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
        --with-pg-lib
        --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
        --with-pq-dir
        --without-pq-dir
        --with-pq-include
        --without-pq-include=${pq-dir}/include
        --with-pq-lib
        --without-pq-lib=${pq-dir}/lib
        --with-pqlib
        --without-pqlib
        --with-libpq-dir
        --without-libpq-dir
        --with-libpq-include
        --without-libpq-include=${libpq-dir}/include
        --with-libpq-lib
        --without-libpq-lib=${libpq-dir}/lib
        --with-libpqlib
        --without-libpqlib
        --with-ms/libpq-dir
        --without-ms/libpq-dir
        --with-ms/libpq-include
        --without-ms/libpq-include=${ms/libpq-dir}/include
        --with-ms/libpq-lib
        --without-ms/libpq-lib=${ms/libpq-dir}/lib
        --with-ms/libpqlib
        --without-ms/libpqlib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.1.0/pg-1.3.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.3.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.1.0/pg-1.3.5/gem_make.out
```

I have done `sudo yum install postgresql-devel`

```
Package postgresql-devel-9.2.24-7.el7_9.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

and `curl -I https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connected

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 4701495
...
```

I have also done `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`

What should I do to install pg gem?

Comment: Is `libpq-devel` installed?

Comment: Hi @NasirRiley, `yum install libpq-devel` `No package libpq-devel available.` I have installed `postgresql-devel`

Comment: Add the output of `locate libpq-fe.h` and locate `libpq.so` to the question.

Comment: Hi @NasirRiley, `whereis libpq-fe.h` `libpq-fe: /usr/include/libpq-fe.h` and `whereis libpq.so` `libpq: /usr/lib64/libpq.so /usr/include/libpq`

Comment: Did you try what the message says and `gem install pg --with-pg-include=/usr/include/libpq-fe.h --with-pg-lib=/usr/lib64/libpq.so`?

Comment: Hi @NasirRiley, yes tried with --with-pq-include as well

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Centos 7) pg_config was required, so I installed dev package with:

```
yum install postgresql-devel
```

and then I had to add it to path with

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-12/bin
```

I'm using pgsql 12, you may want to point to your version folder.